# Django admin add page, how to, autofill with latest data(0002)+1=0003

Tags: python, django, admin

When adding a new data, can we automatically add a dynamic default data where the value is previous recorded data(0002)+1=0003

Answer (score 1):

Not reliably. What will happen if multiple people access it at the same time is that data will be overwritten. Let the PK serve its purpose, behind the scenes.